# Change site description to include Wolfram Language

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Update:** The change has been made (see rm-rf's comment).

---

Currently the site description is

> Mathematica® Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Wolfram Mathematica.

Wolfram is soon going to launch [several products](http://www.wolfram.com/products/?source=nav) most of which use the same programming language now branded as *Wolfram Language*.  As a result of this rebranding, there already appears to be confusion among people new to Mathematica / Wolfram Language about what the difference between these things is.  It is likely that people interested in "Wolfram Language" won't be searching for Mathematica ([example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50600/using-wolfram-language-without-raspberry-pi)).

What Mathematica.SE is mostly about is really the common programming language of all the WRI products.

The launch of these products is imminent ([today?](https://twitter.com/stephen_wolfram/status/480500116491472896)).

Therefore it is important that the sit description should explicitly include the words *Wolfram Language*.  I suggest changing it ASAP to

> Mathematica® Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Mathematica and the Wolfram Language.

---

A related question is how to direct traffic looking for Wolfram Language (e.g. [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-language)) to this site if/when this search term (tag) becomes popular.

Comment: If it looks like the Wolfram branding will put more emphasis on "Wolfram" products, one of which is Mathematica, consideration should be given to a wholesale rename of the SE site e.g to 'Wolfram Language / Mathematica'.  Is there a mechanism in SE for a rename ?  Is there any precedent where a programming language has been re-named/branded?

Comment: @PlaysDice That is certainly something that will come up.  However, this meta thread is for changing the site description only, which I think should happen ASAP.  There should be a separate thread for discussion about the name.  The reason: many people, including myself, have a strong emotional attachment to the name Mathematica. There are objective counterarguments as well. If a renaming does happen, it won't happen quickly.  Let's take care of the urgent things first (I don't think anyone will disagree about changing the *description*, so that will be quick).

Comment: Understood!  Can you guide what (votes on the Q?) needs to be done to approve the proposed revised description?

Comment: @PlaysDice I do not know who has the power to change descriptions (moderators or SE staff).  However, if the question has many upvotes, then it's clear that the community agrees and the change will happen (regardless of who has to make it).

Comment: Ok. I throw my +1 pebble.

Comment: This is quite a straightforward change, and so I've made it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Do "all the WRI products" include WolframAlpha?